# Mac build ffmpeg for Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I want to compile ffmpeg on my Mac. The ndk version is r19c and the FFmpeg version is 4.1.3. The build script is copied from [this article](https://medium.com/@karthikcodes1999/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-4-0-for-android-b988326f16f2). But there are some problems when compiling, as follows：

[image]

Thanks！！！

Answer (score 1):

Starting with NDK r19 everything you need can be found in the `<NDK>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/<host>` directory.

Stripped down example for arm64-v8a targeting API 28:

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path/to/android-ndk-r19c
export PATH=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:$PATH

SYSROOT=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot
AS=aarch64-linux-android28-clang
CC=aarch64-linux-android28-clang
CXX=aarch64-linux-android28-clang++
ARCH=aarch64
CPU=armv8-a    

./configure \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --as=$AS \
    --cc=$CC \
    --cxx=$CXX \
    --target-os=android \
    --arch=$ARCH \
    --cpu=$CPU \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    [ ... other configure options ...]
```

Comment: After this configuration, may i know how to use it in Android Studio, As I am new to Native development everything seems to be confused for me.

Comment: @Gunaseelan https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html